# How to read an xmi file from rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xmi

I have several models saved in an xmi format. 
And I need to read them from some application in rails.
I don't need to build a model from de xmi file, I just need to read some values that the xmi file has. 
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: xmi files can be parsed in a xml parser because it should be xml compliant, any reason why not just use a xml parser for this?

Comment: Well the original idea is to find a parser to read an xmi file from rails. I guess the xmi file could be parsed with the xml parser, and then it would be easier to read it. Am I right?

Comment: AFAIK there are no native xmi parser for Ruby. So xml parser is pretty much the next best thing, davidb's answer should be sufficient for you (for anything more complicated you can use nokogiri gem). By the way, xml parsing is not Rails specific, in your case it is Ruby specific.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file content and parse it at a hash:

```
fh=File.open("filename.xml", "r")
data=Hash.from_xml(fh.read)
```

This is just an example. All you need is the xml as a string and then you can use Hash.from_xml to parse it and work with it as a hash.